# Symfony 4 Swift Mailer doesn't send mails

Tags: symfony, swiftmailer

I´m working in a localhost server with `Symfony 4` and `FOSUserBundle`.  I can't manage to receive the email confirmation when a new user is registered.

I have tried the following post but it´s not working in my case:
[Symfony 4 SwiftMailer Gmail : Email not sent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48915515/symfony-4-swiftmailer-gmail-email-not-sent)

I have tried to configure SwiftMailer to send using `gmail smtp server` and `mailtrap smtp server` without success. Also I have checked `dev.log` and no errors are found.

I´m not sure which is the right file to configure Swift Mailer (.env or packages/dev/swiftmailer.yaml).  Right now the configuration is the following:

.env file:

```
MAILER_URL=gmail://***@gmail.com:***@localhost
```

swiftmailer.yaml:

```
swiftmailer:
transport:        gmail
username:         ***@gmail.com
password:         ***
host:             localhost
port:             465
encryption:       ssl
auth-mode:        login
spool: { type: 'memory' }
stream_options:
    ssl:
        allow_self_signed: true
        verify_peer: false
        verify_peer_name: false
```

Any ideas? It´s not mandatory to use gmail as the smtp server.

Thanks beforehand.

SOLUTION:

The problem was in the /config/test/fos_user.yaml file:

I changed:

```
service:
  mailer: 'fos_user.mailer.noop'
```

To:

```
service:
  mailer: 'fos_user.mailer.default'
```

Documentation: http://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSUserBundle/emails.html

Also I have accepted less secure connections from the gmail account setting in order to work.

Comment: Can you try to remove parameters port, host, auth-mode and retry a send plz

Comment: Still not working

Comment: If you try to send a mail via the `swiftmailer:email:send` command, what is the output?

Comment: I have edited the question to add the solution.  Thanks for the comments and help ;)

Comment: Glad you solved your issue. Please remove the solution from your question, put it in an answer and accept your answer, it might help others.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem with Symfony 4. My packages version
swiftmailer/swiftmailer                     v6.1.0
symfony/swiftmailer-bundle                  v3.2.2
When I used configuration:
  swiftmailer:
      url: '%env(MAILER_URL)%'
      spool: { type: 'memory' }

The emails were not send and no exception occurred.
Then I change the settings into:

`swiftmailer:
    url: '%env(MAILER_URL)%'
    spool:
            type: 'file'
            path: '%kernel.cache_dir%/swiftmailer/spool'`

And tried command:

`php bin/console swiftmailer:spool:send --env=dev -vvv`

And I saw the error:

`[Swift_SwiftException]

  No IDN encoder found (install the intl extension or the true/punycode package`
So I installed true/punycode package via:

`composer req true/punycode`

and now emails are sending fine also with spool memory.

Answer (score 2):

Default behaviour of Symfony mailer is to send the email messages immediately, but as you configured, it will "spool" the emails instead of sending them directly.

```
spool: { type: 'memory' }
```

Sending the messages from the spool is done separately, with a console command:

```
php bin/console swiftmailer:spool:send --env=dev
```

@see more docs [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/email/spool.html)

UPDATE:
As @nek said on the first comment, the the memory spool send the mail immediately (if none exception occured). The spool:send command is only required when using the file spool.

Comment: The `memory` spool send the mail immediately (if none exception occured). The `spool:send` command is only required when using the `file` spool.