# Symfony4 swiftMailer doesn't work

Tags: swiftmailer, symfony4

I have some problem with swiftmailer in symfony4. When I send email, I don't get any error and Symfony Profiler display something like that:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tCYc0.png]

But I don't get email on my gmail. And I don't really understand what email should be in setFrom(), is there should not be email which I use in my env?? Here is controller

```
 public function sendMessage(\Swift_Mailer $mailer)
{
    $request = Request::createFromGlobals();
    $values = [];

    $values['name'] = $request->request->get('name');
    $values['phone_number'] = $request->request->get('phone_number');
    $values['email'] = $request->request->get('email');
    $values['message'] = $request->request->get('message');


    $message = (new \Swift_Message('Message from example.org'))
        ->setFrom($values['email'])
        ->setTo('mail@example.com')
        ->setBody($this->renderView('email.html.twig',
                array('name' => $values['name'], 'phone_number' => $values['phone_number'], 'message' => $values['message'])
            ), 'text/html');

    $mailer->send($message);

    return new Response('Thank you for your email');
}
```

and configuration in `.env` file

> MAILER_URL="gmail://myUsername:myPassword@smtp.gmail.com"

Somebody know what is wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mailer symfony 4 not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48230130/mailer-symfony-4-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue with Gmail, not with swiftmailer. If you use another mail server you won't have this problem. See also: [this same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48230130/mailer-symfony-4-not-working/48305459#48305459).

Comment: So I change mailer_url, and now this look like that: MAILER_URL="smtp://serwer9999999.home.pl" And I get the same result.

Comment: Do you have a working mail server? Configuration could look something like this: `MAILER_URL=smtp://mail.server.com:465?encryption=ssl&auth_mode=login&username=your@username.com&password=yourpassword`

Comment: Ok, I did that, and now it's problem with connection, perhaps @ in my username can be a problem?

Comment: This completely depends on your mailserver. Some servers have a username that is like an email-address others can simply be 'somename'. You have to find out which is your username you need to use the server.

Comment: So connection works, but now I have something like that Exception occurred while flushing email queue: Expected response code 250 but got code "550", with message "550 5.1.8 Sender address rejected ", and with the same configuration it didn't show up earlier.